# Method with Algorithm that share results with other class members

Tags: c#

I have a Strategy class which I use as:

```
Strategy strategy = Strategy.Name("Sym").Rule<Rule1>().Rule<Rule2>();
```

I need a method `Algorithm` in `Strategy` where I define a set of calculations. Maybe:

```
Strategy strategy = Strategy.Name("Sym").Rule<Rule1>().Rule<Rule2>()
                            .Algorithm(newValue => {
                              Double r1 = newValue ^ 2;
                              Double r2 = r1 * 45;  
                            });
```

And a method `Compute` which when called would run the `Algorithm` with a new value:

```
strategy.Compute(newValue);
```

And I need to share the values, in this example r1 and r2, with the strategy Rules.

At the moment my Strategy class is as follows:

```
  public class Strategy {

    private String Name; 
    private IList<Rule> _rules = new List<Rule>();

    public static Strategy Name(String name) {
      return new Strategy { Name = name);
    }

    public Strategy Rule<T>() where T: Rule, new() {
      _rules.Add(new T());
      return this;
    }
  
  }
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Will the amount of variables to share with the rules depend on the amount of rules added to your strategy, can it change? Will the order in which the rules were added dictate the order in which variables from the algorithm are passed to the rules?

Comment: I'm thinking that to get the `r1` and `r2` variables that are local to your lambda, you would have to either have to take a lambda that returns a tuple with those values, or use `out` parameters. I'm assuming you're storing the lambda somewhere in your object, you could then call it to get `r1` and `r2` and pass it to your `Rule` classes.

Comment: @Prolog The number of variables do not change depending on the number of rules. And the order of the rules do not affect how the variables area passed. Basically the algorithm is a centralised point to calculate and update some variables that are shared to all rules.

Comment: @AlexRiveron In the example I posted I am calculating R1 and R2. But in other situations I might have R1, R2 and R3.

Comment: `newValue ^ 2` do you know that the `^` operator is the bitwise XOR and not exponentiation in C#? Doing a `double ^ int` is rather meaningless also in terms of bitwise operations.

Comment: You cannot use `LINQ` to set values in a class.

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all clear what the intent of the code is. My best guess is as follows:

Use a `Func<>` to store the algorithm in a property and call it with `Alogrithm(args)`

```
public class Strategy
{
    public Strategy(string name)
    {
        this.Name=name;
        this.Rules = new List<Rule>();
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public Strategy Rule<T>() where T : Rule, new()
    {
        Rules.Add(new T());
        return this;
    }
    public Func<Strategy, double, double> Algorithm { get; set; }

    public IList<Rule> Rules { get; }
}

public abstract class Rule
{
    public static readonly Rule Start = new StartRule();
    public static readonly Rule End = new EndRule();
}
public class StartRule : Rule
{
    public double X { get; set; } = 0;
}
public class EndRule : Rule
{
    public double Y { get; set; } = 100;
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = new Strategy("Test");
        s.Algorithm = (st, val) =>
        {
            double r1 = st.Rules.OfType<EndRule>().FirstOrDefault().Y;
            return 35.0*r1 + val;
        };

        double ans = s.Rule<EndRule>().Algorithm(s, 5.5);
        // 3505.5
    }
}
```